# Postgres: how to excecute the query for Sum as it is giving error?

Tags: postgresql

I am using sum function to find the total but getting error.
Here is the query:

```
select sum(col1) 
from table_name 
where col2="abc"
```

> ```
> Error: function sum(text) does not exist
> Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
> ```

Comment: why are you storing numbers in a `text` column? If you have a chance to fix that broken design, do it **now**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming the `text` column contains *text* numbers, not actual integers, then it would explain the error you are seeing.  You might get around this by first casting `text` to integer, then summing:

```
SELECT SUM(text::int)
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks ,it was text

Comment: sure will do that